# VB.NET DataGridView ButtonColumn How to resize smaller than its cell

Tags: vb.net

how do I resize the buttons in the buttoncolumn of my datagridview programmatically? I know some would say I can do it with padding but in my experience that would make the cells bigger which I don't like to happen. What I want to do is to resize my buttons without changing the size of the cells. Any code snippet will be helpful. Thanks geniuses!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of button as 50% or so to make it look smaller inside the Grid cell.